# fix html5 tags IE8 not working when loading at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

To fix compatibility of html5 tags (article, aside, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section) with IE8, i normally add this javascript:

```
document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("aside");
document.createElement("footer");
document.createElement("header");
document.createElement("hgroup");
document.createElement("nav");
document.createElement("section");
```

and in the css file

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, ection, summary {
    display: block;
}
```

If I load the JS in the "head" it works correctly, but now I'm loading all JS at the bottom of the page (before close "body") doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The elements have to be "known" before their first appearence. Btw, why don't you use [html5shiv.js](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/) for this?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the code you're using here only deals with one part of the problem (loading a page with HTML5 elements). But there are still further bugs that could catch you or your visitors out. If you have dynamic content on the page or you want to print the page for example, your fix will be insufficient. You should use the full html5shiv to fix the issue properly rather than doing a half-job.

Comment: Thanks for the info Andreas and Spudley, i will take both suggestions in account.

Comment: Please don't use the "fix" tag unless you're talking about FIX protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load fixing javascript before html5 tags that ie8 should know about them. Otherwise ie8 treats those tags as HTMLUnknownElement.
So, that js should be in head tag. BTW, doesn't the following code smaller? =)

```
var tags='article|aside|footer|header|hgroup|nav|section'.split('|'), i=0, max=tags.length;
for(;i<max;i++) {
    document.createElement(tags[i]);
}
```